# Does the HEAD reference in Git, point to the tag or the SHA-1 value when checked out by specifying the tag?

Tags: git, version-control

In Git, when we check out to a specific commit using the following command:

`git checkout <commit>`

If we use the tag (assume that commit has a tag referencing it) for that particular commit, instead of its SHA-1 value in place of **< commit >**, will the **HEAD reference**, point to the tag (i.e. will the HEAD act as a **symbolic reference**) or point to the SHA-1 value (i.e. act as a **reference**)?

Thank you!

Comment: Just try checking out a tag and then looking at `.git/HEAD`?

Comment: You can also use `git symbolic-ref` to attempt to read a name (any name, not just `HEAD`) to see whether it contains a symbolic reference, or a raw hash ID. The command will fail if the reference contains a raw hash ID. This will show that checking out a tag results in a detached HEAD.

Comment: As an aside, symbolic refs could, in theory, attach to *any* ref (existing or not), but Git currently constrains them to attach only to *branch names*, i.e., refs whose full name starts with `refs/heads/`. It's not clear exactly what the advantages and disadvantages would be, if `HEAD` could contain `ref: refs/tags/v2.1` for instance. But this is at least currently forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, a Git tag is basically just a pointer to some commit.  This is similar to a branch name, which logically also points to the recent commit of a branch.  Checking out either a tag name or a branch name will move the HEAD to the relevant commit.

To your exact question, a tag is a pointer to a commit (which has a unique SHA-1 hash value), and checking out a tag will move the HEAD to point to the commit referred to by the tag.

Answer (score 2):

you can see exactly what the HEAD is referencing:

```
<.git/HEAD
```

HEAD is just a file.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man git checkout`,[1] these are the only things that you
can feed this command:

```
git checkout [snip] [<branch>]
git checkout [snip] [<commit>]
git checkout [snip] [<pathspc>]
```

Notably it says nothing about `ref` as a general thing that you can make
`HEAD` point to—only `<branch>` and `<commit>`.

Further, the only mention of tags is under the section “Detached
`HEAD`” (`v2.0` is a tag):

> It is sometimes useful to be able to checkout a commit that is not at
> the tip of any named branch, or even to create a new commit that is
> not referenced by a named branch. Let’s look at what happens when we
> checkout commit b (here we show two ways this may be done):
>
> ```
> $ git checkout v2.0  # or
> $ git checkout master^^
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Notice that regardless of which checkout command we use, `HEAD` now
> refers directly to commit b. This is known as being in detached `HEAD`
> state.

So if you checkout a commit directly or through a tag the result is the
same; you are in “detached `HEAD`” state, pointing directly at a commit.

So I would say that `HEAD` may only point to a *ref* (and no other kind
of ref) of type branch:

```
# The contents of `.git/HEAD`
ref: refs/heads/main
```

Or else it has to point directly at an object:

```
# The contents of `.git/HEAD` (in “detached `HEAD`” state)
17abc2521ca2f1331cc8c4a02b501443fd92f11d
```

#### Notes

1. Git 2.40.0